# Request Certificate points to wrong Server

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, certificate, certificate-authority

We migrated a while ago from SBS 2008 to Windows Server 2012 R2. The new Server is also the Certificationauthority. But when I want to renew a certificate, a get the error messsage "Error: RPC Server is not available".

Since the URL shown in the error message points to "oldserver.domain.local" and not to "newserver.domain.local", this makes sense.

How can I change the address to the new server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you didn't decommission old server and its reference is still exists in Active Directory. You need to remove stale records. Here is a CA decommission guide: [How to Decommission a Windows Enterprise Certification Authority and How to Remove All Related Objects](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/3527.how-to-decommission-a-windows-enterprise-certification-authority-and-how-to-remove-all-related-objects.aspx)

I suspect that you already removed CA server itself, so you need to perform sections 6 and 7 in referenced article.

Comment: It solved this problem. However, now the ca templates on the new server can not be loaded...

Comment: I hope you didn't remove certificate templates from Active Directory? Check if they are listed in `certtmpl.msc` MMC snap-in.

Comment: No, they are there. It shows 34 Templates

Comment: I openend a new question, see https://serverfault.com/questions/940508/certificate-authority-does-not-show-templates . I would be gratefull for your advice.